# Is there a particular name for the supporting line defined by one sided derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Suppose $c: (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a concave function. For some $a \in (0,1)$, the mapping $$x \mapsto c'(a-)(x - a) + c(a)$$ is a supporting line for $c$, where $c'(a-)$ is the left derivative of $c$ at $a$. Because there are possibly many supporting lines at the same point, I am wondering if there is a particular name for the supporting line defined by left (or right) derivative as above. For example, is it common to call it left supporting line?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This would be the *directional derivative* in the *negative* direction. However, as far as i know there is no special name for this as the one-dimensional case is usually not the most interesting one and the concept of "left" does not make sense in higher dimensions.

Comment: Thanks! Then, can I call it ``the supporting line of $c$ at $a$ with slope $c'(a-)$?

Comment: This would definitely be non-standard notation. Usually the prime symbol is reserved for differentiable functions. For the directional derivate of a function $f$ at a point $x_0$ in direction $-u$ one uses either $df(x_0; -u)$ or $f'(x_0; -u)$. In your case this would give the supporting line with slope $c'(a;-1)$.